# Fix name tag on a face in iPhone photos app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app

I tagged some pictures with a wrong person in Photos app of iPhone ios 10.2. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click "i" (for get information", click on the face of the person then in the name tag - and correct the name just as you would for any other mac item name change